# c++ if statement is causing an infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

In my function, I added a if statement to keep the users inputting the correct coordinates, if the first if statement is false, it will cause an infinite loop. IF the first if statement is correct and the second if statement is false, it works perfectly fine.

```
void Sheep::sheepProcess(BoardSet& board)
{
    char middle;

    cout << "Your move? ";
    cin >> x1 >> y1 >> middle >> x2 >> y2;
    if (correctInput(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    {
        convertCoordinates(x1, y1, x2, y2); //x=z and y=w

        if(board.legalMoveForSheep(z1, w1, z2, w2))
        {
            board.adjustBoardForSheep(z1, w1, z2, w2);

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Illegal Move, Try again" << endl;
            sheepProcess(board);

        }

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Illegal input, Try again" << endl;
        sheepProcess(board);
    }

}
```

If you need more if the code, such as the bools. let me know

Edit:

```
class Sheep {
public:

    void sheepProcess(BoardSet& board);
    void convertCoordinates(char x1, int y1, char x2, int y2);
    void initalizedItems();


private:
    char x1, x2;
    int y1, y2, z1, z2, w1, w2;
};
```

Comment: Only if you keep giving invalid input. Nonetheless, this is much better suited to a loop than recursion.

Comment: Are you inputting characters into a number?

Comment: If not corrected, invalid input only needs to be given once to make future calls to `cin >> ...` fail.

Comment: @DrewDormann I meant invalid input according to `correctInput`, but yes, I think causing the input stream to fail would screw this up.

Comment: If somebody is deliberately trying to crash your system, he can.  C++ does not support tail recursion, so each invalid input adds another stack frame, eventually exceeding the limit.  And that can be done by an automatic process.

Comment: @sftrabbit What would be a better way to turn this into a loop instead of recursion?

Comment: @UnhinderedLimpidity Where you currently make an additional call to `sheepProcess(board)`, it seems that all you really wanted to do was loop back to the top of the function.

Comment: `for(;;) { input; if (end of input) break; process and output; }`

Comment: @Drew Dormann It worked for the second layer of the If statement, so I thought it would work, I think I understand what you are saying though

Comment: @EricJablow: It'd be more accurate to say that C++ does not require tail recursion optimization.  You certainly can do tail recursion in C++, and an implementation surely could perform the optimization if it wanted to.

Comment: @UnhinderedLimpidity As was implied in earlier comments, you're probably getting an infinite loop because `x1`, `y1`, `middle`, `x2`, `y2` were declared as types that don't accept the input the program is given.  Please include their declarations and the input in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not eating the input that's standing ready on `cin`. The next read is getting the very same input which also fails, repeat ad nauseam.

Solution: When you detect there's input standing ready that's not valid, eat it & throw away, complain to user about providing bad input and allow him to retry.

Comment: How would you suggest I eat the input? would I just declare the items in the if statment as 0 if they input correctly or is the a way to just remove the current input?

Comment: Oh, I see I can use the command `cin.clear()` to remove it. Thank you for your help